# What does "$\imath$" (a cursive "i" without a tittle) mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

What does "$\imath$" (a cursive "i" without a tittle) mean?

It seems to be an algebraic symbol, as that was all I was dealing with in the original question.

Here's the original question (I was trying to simplify it and was using cymath.com to check):

$$v = \pm\sqrt{-c^2\left(\frac{t^2}{x^2}-1\right)}\qquad\text{Simpler Form:}\quad v = \pm\sqrt{c^2\left(\frac{t^2}{x^2}-1\right)\imath}$$

Does anyone know what this symbol means? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $i$ is an imaginary number; $i^2=-1$

Comment: [imaginary unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit)?

Comment: I was thinking that, but the weird thing is the missing tittle?

Comment: Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iota#Symbol lists some meanings of the letter 'iota' in mathematics. This looks like the imaginary unit, BUT it would require the iota to be outside the radical to make sens – $\sqrt{-1}$ can be replaced by $i$, not by $\sqrt i$.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol `\iota` $\iota$ (Greek letter iota) is used in some countries as $\sqrt{-1}$.  Others use $i$ or ${\rm i}$ or $j$. The other symbol `\imath` $\imath$ is not intended for this, instead it is used when $i$ has some decoration above it: $\vec{\imath}$ looks better than $\vec{i}$ .

The two are slightly different.  Enlarged view:

[image: a1]

Also, $i$ is not "cursive" it is "italic".  Here is "cursive", also known as "script".  But you can do this only if you have the proper fonts installed.

[image: a2]